# get exact date time from SharePoint date time field irrespective of user time zone using Javascript

Tags: office-365, 2016, jsom

I have a DateTime field in Sharepoint

This is the value that I get in Javascript

```
"2017-12-06T19:00:00Z"
```

Now the actual value in SharePoint field is

```
12/6/2017 11:00 AM
```

How can I change it to this value irrespective of browser time zone in javascript?

Currently I tried 
`new Date(item.StartTime)` which gives me `Dec 07 2017 00:30:00 GMT+0530`

I also tried

```
moment(item.StartTime).format("hh:mm A") which gives `"07:12:2017 12:30 AM"` which is again not the actual value
```

Comment: "2017-12-06T19:00:00Z" is the actual value in the SharePoint field. "12/6/2017 11:00 AM" is the value based on the current web and/or user.

Comment: no but when I try new Date("2017-12-06T19:00:00Z") its giving a different date

Comment: I also tried Moment JS

Comment: Go to your site settings > regional settings (`https://site-coll-url/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx`) and check if they are correct. If not, update it to the correct time zone and then run the code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Gautam, it is important to take into consideration what timezone has been set in the regional settings of your SP site.

As per my understanding, if the SP timezone is set as 'America/Los_Angeles' then at the time of saving the item SharePoint will convert the date time you entered in ISO string format like this "2017-12-06T19:00:00Z" and save it.
While displaying the date time in any list view, SharePoint will automatically convert the ISO string to the timezone set in regional settings ("12/6/2017 11:00 AM" in this case).

Hence to summarize if you want to show the ISO String to user in agreement with what is being displayed in list view, simply convert the ISO string to the timezone set in your site's regional settings.

With the help of moment library it can be done fairly easily as shown below:

```
var itemDate = moment('2017-12-06T19:00:00Z')
console.log(moment.tz(itemDate,'America/Los_Angeles').format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS Z'));
//outputs 12-06-2017 11:00:00 -08:00
```